# Pandas DF Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of student responses[S1-S82] and each strand corresponding to the response. I want to know the count of each response given wrt each strand. If the student marked answer correctly I want to know the strand name and no. of correct responses, if the answer is wrong I want to know the strand name and no. of wrong responses(similar to value counts). I am attaching a screenshot of the dataframe.
https://prnt.sc/1125odu

I have written the following code
`data_transposed['Counts'] = data_transposed.groupby(['STRAND-->'])['S1'].transform('count')`
but it is really not helping me get what I want. I am looking for an option similar to value_counts to plot the data.
Please look into it and help me. Thank you,

Comment: provide your data in a usable text format. `print(df.to_markdown())`` or `print(df.to_string())`

Comment: Can you please share the data as a text. Here's a Stack Overflow wiki to help you share your [pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Hi can I share a screenshot of the data ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1127iub Here is the screenshot of the data.

Comment: screenshot is not useful - can't use OCR to populate a DF to show you a possible solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to groupby the Strands for each student S1 thru S82.

Here's how I would do it.

- Step 1: Create a DataFrame with groupby `Strand-->` where value is 0
- Step 2: Create another DataFrame with groupby `Strand-->` where value
  is 1
- Step 3: Add a column in each of the dataframes and assign value of 0 or 1 to represent which data it grouped
- Step 4: Concatenate both dataframes.
- Step 5: Rearrange the columns to have `Strand-->`, `val`, then all students `S1` thru `S82`
- Step 6: Sort the dataframe using `Strand-->` so you get the values in
  the right order.

The code is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Strand-->':['Geometry','Geometry','Geometry','Geometry','Mensuration',
                                'Mensuration','Mensuration','Geometry','Algebra','Algebra',
                                'Comparing Quantities','Geometry','Data Handling','Geometry','Geometry']}
for i in range(1,83): d ['S'+str(i)] = np.random.randint(0,2,size=15) 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)

df1 = df.groupby('Strand-->').agg(lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())
df1['val'] = 0
df2 = df.groupby('Strand-->').agg(lambda x: x.ne(0).sum())
df2['val'] = 1
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).reset_index()
dx = [0,-1] + [i for i in range(1,83)]
df3 = df3[df3.columns[dx]].sort_values('Strand-->').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df3)
```

The output of this will be as follows:

Original DataFrame:

```
               Strand-->  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  ...  S77  S78  S79  S80  S81  S82
0               Geometry   0   1   0   0   1  ...    1    0    0    0    1    0
1               Geometry   0   0   0   1   1  ...    1    1    1    0    0    0
2               Geometry   1   1   1   0   0  ...    0    0    1    0    0    0
3               Geometry   0   1   1   0   1  ...    1    0    0    1    0    1
4            Mensuration   1   1   1   0   1  ...    0    1    1    1    0    0
5            Mensuration   0   1   1   1   0  ...    1    0    0    1    1    0
6            Mensuration   1   0   1   1   1  ...    0    1    0    0    1    0
7               Geometry   1   0   1   1   1  ...    1    1    1    0    0    1
8                Algebra   0   0   1   0   1  ...    1    1    0    0    1    1
9                Algebra   0   1   0   1   1  ...    1    1    1    1    0    1
10  Comparing Quantities   1   1   0   1   1  ...    1    1    0    1    1    0
11              Geometry   1   1   1   1   0  ...    0    0    1    0    1    0
12         Data Handling   1   1   0   0   0  ...    1    0    1    1    0    0
13              Geometry   1   1   1   0   0  ...    1    1    1    1    0    0
14              Geometry   0   1   0   0   1  ...    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Updated DataFrame:
Note here that column `'val'` will be `0` or `1`. If `0`, then it is the count of `0`s. If `1`, then it is the count of `1`s.

```
              Strand-->  val  S1  S2  S3  S4  ...  S77  S78  S79  S80  S81  S82
0               Algebra    0   2   1   1   1  ...    0    0    1    1    1    0
1               Algebra    1   0   1   1   1  ...    2    2    1    1    1    2
2  Comparing Quantities    0   0   0   1   0  ...    0    0    1    0    0    1
3  Comparing Quantities    1   1   1   0   1  ...    1    1    0    1    1    0
4         Data Handling    0   0   0   1   1  ...    0    1    0    0    1    1
5         Data Handling    1   1   1   0   0  ...    1    0    1    1    0    0
6              Geometry    0   4   2   3   5  ...    3    4    2    6    5    6
7              Geometry    1   4   6   5   3  ...    5    4    6    2    3    2
8           Mensuration    0   1   1   0   1  ...    2    1    2    1    1    3
9           Mensuration    1   2   2   3   2  ...    1    2    1    2    2    0
```

Comment: This has helped in resolving the problem, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

For single student you can do:

```
df.groupby(['Strand-->', 'S1']).size().to_frame(name = 'size').reset_index()
```

If you want to calculate all students at once you can do:

```
df_m = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Strand-->'], value_vars=df.columns[1:]).rename({'variable':'result'},axis=1).sort_values(['result'])
df_m['result'].groupby([df_m['Strand-->'],df_m['value']]).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi, yes I am looking for a way to count the 0's and 1's but I also want wrt the strand how many are right or wrong i.e  in strand geometry how many are 1's and 0's of S1, in mensuration how many are 1's and 0's of S1 like that for all the strands, and I can apply it to all students.

Comment: Hi thats exactly what I am looking for. The output is as follows https://prnt.sc/1127nvd. Can u also guide me how to plot this data, in a pie chart or a donut as I could easily plot this in power bi but I want to do the plotting in pandas using available visualization libraries.

Comment: There are many visualization tutorials online, you can refer to this as a staring point: https://www.dataforeverybody.com/matplotlib-seaborn-pie-charts/

Comment: Sure, will refer to the tutorial. Thanks a lot for ur timely help.

Comment: Please avoid doing loops and merging. You are merging the dataframe 82 times to get the result.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is an ugly solution, updated the answer again with value_counts method.